# How to catch array index(es) on custom variant

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, variant

I'm reading about TCustomVariantType and would like to know if there's a way to override the behaviour when a variable of the custom variant type gets called with one or more array indexes. If I do a quick debug with the debug DCU's on `a[1]` where `a` is a variant, I see `_VarArrayGet` gets called, but it funnels to a call to [`SafeArrayPtrOfIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891260.aspx) or [`SafeArrayGetElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891255.aspx), without a way to provide an alternative. I see older versions used to have a VariantManager, but this is deprecated. Is there a way to replace the `_VarArrayGet` pointer?

Comment: Not obviously, to me, possible. What's the motivation?

Comment: Since you're asking, for https://github.com/stijnsanders/TMongoWire if a BSON has an array of documents with a similar set of keys, it would help performance if you could iterate the array with a single IBSONDocument with internally the same array of record for the keys. Kind of recycling memory instead of dropping and re-allocating all the time. It would be nice to get this working with a plain `a[x]` syntax, but for now I guess I'll have to use something like IEnumVariant (ugh).

Comment: I've had another look, and I guess I could rephrase the question: with TVariantManager deprecated, how is the system wired up so that `a[x]` ends up as a call to `VarArrayGet(a,[x])`? Do I need to go so deep into the system as to modify Variants.pas and it's dcu's for this?

Answer (score 0):

> How is the system wired up so that a[x] ends up as a call to VarArrayGet(a,[x])?

The compiler in modern versions of Delphi has built in knowledge of variants and hard-wires the call to `VarArrayGet`. Look at the code the x86 compiler emits:

```
d := V[0];
```

is translated into:

```
004234D7 6A00             push $00
004234D9 6A01             push $01
004234DB 6858AF4200       push $0042af58
004234E0 8D45C8           lea eax,[ebp-$38]
004234E3 50               push eax
004234E4 E81BD8FFFF       call @VarArrayGet
004234E9 83C410           add esp,$10
004234EC 8D45C8           lea eax,[ebp-$38]
004234EF E864B8FFFF       call @VarToReal
004234F4 DD1D68AF4200     fstp qword ptr [$0042af68]
004234FA 9B               wait
```

There is simply no extension point available to you.

Your best option if you wish to change the behaviour is to use a runtime code detour.

Comment: I guess there's no chance of 'overwriting' `@VarArrayGet`? Any odd dirty trick would do. (What do you mean by a runtime code detour?)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking  I'm wondering what more you are looking for at this question